# A generic error occurred in GDI+. at System.Drawing.Image.Save

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

Hi I am getting this error while  saving an Image at the given path

```
string WriteImage(string data, string imgPath)
{           
    try
    {
        data = "*" + data + "*";
        Bitmap barcode = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        Font threeOfNine = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 60, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(barcode);
        SizeF dataSize = graphics.MeasureString(data, threeOfNine);
        barcode = new Bitmap(barcode, dataSize.ToSize());
        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(barcode);
        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;
        graphics.DrawString(data, threeOfNine, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
        graphics.Flush();
        threeOfNine.Dispose();
        graphics.Dispose();
        barcode.SetResolution(300, 300);
        barcode.Save(imgPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return imgPath.Substring(imgPath.LastIndexOf("\\")+1);
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Dont know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Is it a file permissions issue? What if you don't set the resolution? Have you verified the results of `dataSize.ToSize()`? As side notes: you aren't disposing of your original bitmap or graphics object nor the final bitmap object. JPEG is for photos. It will not look good with rendered text.

Comment: I tried your code, and it works for me -- I created a "*Hello world*" bitmap successfully.  When you catch the exception, you should examine it to see what it actually is, e.g. as follows: `catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); return "" }` This should tell you your problem; probably your file path is bad.

Comment: where are you saving the file, if the program does not have write permissions to the directory (for example `c:\SomeFile.jpeg`) it will throw the error you are getting.

Comment: Yes the permissions arent set properly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, I'm not seeing any problem.  The following version of your code outputs information in the event of an error so you can debug it.  It also disposes of resources properly:

```
    public static string WriteImage(string data, string imgPath)
    {
        try
        {
            data = "*" + data + "*";
            using (var dummyBitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1))
            using (var threeOfNine = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 60, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point))
            {
                SizeF dataSize;
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(dummyBitmap))
                {
                    dataSize = graphics.MeasureString(data, threeOfNine);
                }
                using (var barcode = new Bitmap(dummyBitmap, dataSize.ToSize()))
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(barcode))
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
                {
                    graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                    graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;
                    graphics.DrawString(data, threeOfNine, brush, 0, 0);
                    graphics.Flush();
                    barcode.SetResolution(300, 300);
                    barcode.Save(imgPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    return imgPath.Substring(imgPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error saving string \"" + data + "\" to a bitmap at location: " + imgPath);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return "";
        }
    }
```